# How to fix CPU problems in Windows EventLog service?

Tags: windows, performance, event-log, high-cpu-usage, unresponsive

The EventLog service in my machine (running under `svchost.exe`) is using a lot of CPU. I assume it's because some application, driver or component is generating too many logs. How can I spot this offender?

Comment: Use Task Manager details to find what is causing this. Svchost is down near the bottom and you can click on details. See: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/svchost-exe-process-in-windows/

Comment: I would suggest, create a etl trace when the problem is happening.  E.g. `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` leave it for 20-30 seconds when you have the problem and then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl` You don't really want to trace more than 30 seconds ideally.  Once you have the etl file, get Windows Performance Analyzer from the Store and load the trace file.  Either the CPU sampled view will clearly show the issue or you can start filter across all stacks for API calls such as `ReportEvent`, `OpenEventLog`, etc to see which processes are making the calls. You will need symbols loaded!

Comment: If you need help, maybe zip and share the ETL file.